# How to send folder or a file via network using cmd commands

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd

I am new at python and I am a student. In our home everyone has a computer and they have all have administrator account and the password of them are the same. I am trying to make a program that sends a folder or folders from my PC to other computers. I used cmd command "net use" to get access to all of the computers using the administrator account and used "xcopy" to copy folders to other computers.

The problem is that, when I use the `net use` command it says `command successfully executed` but when I try to use `xcopy` command it can't copy the folder. When I check the code nothing seems wrong to me. Could you help me find the problem or could I do this in some other way without using `cmd` or with using `cmd`?  And how can a get the machine name and the username of the computers that I want to send folders to and use it in the code instead of manualy writing it like I did in the script of mine ?

This is the script that I wrote :

```
import os
import subprocess

def check(a):
    checkpath="\\\\"+a+"\\c$\\users"
    if os.path.exists(checkpath):  # this is the function to check if the net use command worked and get access to other computer
        return True

usernumber=1000 #ı adjust the usernames and machine names of the computers like "a1000,a1001 ..." 
notsendto=[]    #and "m4000,m4001" to make it easy to get access a stands for account m stands for machine


machinenames=["m4001","m4002","m4003","m4004","m4005","m4006","m4007"]
path=input("write the path that you want to send: ")

for i in machinenames:
    usernumber+=1
    subprocess.Popen("net use \\\\"+i+"\\c$  /user:"+i+"\\administrator P.a$$word /p:yes")

    if check(i):
        subprocess.Popen("xcopy "+path+" \\\\"+i+"\\c$\\users\\"+str(usernumber)+"\\desktop\\Incoming!!! /s /i")
    else:
        print("could not send to"+i)
```

Comment: You don't define `kontrol` anywhere.

Comment: @ppperry he has other issues in his code too (like an unterminated string literal). I assume `kontrol` is `check`.

Comment: fyi: you can clean up quite a bit of this by using `str.format` and raw string literals. Instead of `"net use \\\\" + i + "\\c$ /user:" + i + "\\administrator SOMEPASS /p:yes"` you could use `r"net use \\{machinename}\c$ /user:{machinename}\administrator SOMEPASS /p:yes".format(machinename=i)`

Comment: unrelated: `r'\\host\path\to'` (raw string literal) allows to avoid escaping the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess

def check(a):
    checkpath="\\\\"+a+"\\c$\\users"
    if os.path.exists(checkpath):  # this is the function to check if the net use command worked and get access to other computer
        return True

usernumber=1000 #ı adjust the usernames and machine names of the computers like "a1000,a1001 ..." 
notsendto=[]    #and "m4000,m4001" to make it easy to get access a stands for account m stands for machine


machinenames=["m4001","m4002","m4003","m4004","m4005","m4006","m4007"]
path=input("write the path that you want to send: ")

for i in machinenames:
    usernumber+=1
     os.system(r"net use \\"+i+r"\c$ PassWord /u:"+i+r"\usernumber /P:yes")

    if check(i):
        subprocess.Popen("xcopy "+path+" \\\\"+i+"\\c$\\users\\"+str(usernumber)+"\\desktop\\Incoming!!! ")
    else:
        print("could not send to"+i)
```